# Django: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: python, django, cross-domain

I use an image crop tool. But it's turn to me Access-Control-Allow-Origin security error.

I send header to django like that:

```
response = render_to_response('merchant/store_gallery.html', {
    'store': store,
    'form': form,
    'tag': tag,
    'crop_form': crop_form,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

response["Allow-Control-Allow-Origin"] = '*'

return response
```

I tried many header but they are not work.

And When I use [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) enabled, I don't take any error and it's work.

How can I do its plugin work in django ??

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake in your code, it is **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** and not **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin**.

Comment: From what I understand of the SO standards, this should be a comment rather than an answer.  I could be wrong.